# Не получается защитить страницу от неавторизованного пользователя...

Tags: php

В примере, написано, на каждой странице защищенной зоны до тега `<html>` надо поставить код:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($autorize!=1) die ("несанкционированный доступ");

?>
```

Ставлю код, но страница не блокируется.. Сохраняла странцу в формате .php.

Выдает ошибку:

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: во-первых, код неверный.
во-вторых, проблема наверняка кроется в серваке или php (патчи, настройки)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['autorize'] != 1)
    {
        die('Несанкционированный доступ!');
    }
?>
```

Но помните, что в $_SESSION['autorize'] должна быть единица, присвоенная туда в процессе авторизации!

Comment: Спасибо огромное! единица в процессе авторизации присваивается :)

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того каким образом Вы пытаетесь ограничить доступ. Если эта страница должна быть доступна для доступа зарегистрированным пользователям, которые авторизовались на сайте, то делайте как в ответе выше. Но я бы добавил. Вместо `die('Несанкционированный доступ!')`

> `header('Location: адрес страницы с формой авторизации на сайте');
> exit;`

Если эта страница должна быть доступна только для включения, т.е. через `include` или `require`, то тогда в самом верху этой страницы пропишите

> `<?php if (!defined('ACCESS')) {exit('Несанкционированный доступ!')}`

А в файле где вы будете подключать эту страницу создайте константу `define('ACCESS', true)`
Т.е.

> `<?php
> define('ACCESS', true);
> require 'somepage.php';`

Comment: Спасибо за совет! обязательно попробую :)